# If undefined then "0" in appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a efficient way of checking if value is undefined and then converting it to "0".

Code example is

```
$('<tr><td>' + el.firstStat  +'</td><td>'+ el.hours +'</td></tr>').appendTo('#table tbody');
```

Any of these values can be undefined, and in the future there might be more values to add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `||` (OR) operator:

```
el.firstStat = el.firstStat || 0;
el.hours = el.hours || 0;

$('<tr><td>' + el.firstStat  +'</td><td>'+ el.hours +'</td></tr>').appendTo('#table tbody');
```

Because `undefined || 0` is `0`.

Comment: Thank you , that did it!

Comment: @Paran0a Great. Happy holidays! :)

Answer (score 2):

If those are always numeric values, you can use shorthand typecasting (`0 + x`) to get those zeroes:

```
$('<tr><td>' + (0 + el.firstStat)  +'</td><td>'+ (0 + el.hours) +'</td></tr>').appendTo('#table tbody');
```

Or use logical OR:

```
$('<tr><td>' + (el.firstStat || 0)  +'</td><td>'+ (el.hours || 0) +'</td></tr>').appendTo('#table tbody');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<tr><td>' + (el.firstStat==undefined)?"0":el.firstStat  +'</td><td>'+ (el.hours==undefined)?"0":el.hours +'</td></tr>').appendTo('#table tbody');
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary condition :

```
 el.firstStat = el.firstStat === undefined ? 0 : el.firstStat;
```

Or shorter, a double pipe notation :

```
 el.firstStat = el.firstStat || 0;
```